# Implementing a Function as Lambda

Tags: python, lambda

Is there any way to implement the following function as a lambda:

```
def z(s,f):
 for c in s:
  if c in f:f.remove(c)
  else:return 0
 return 1
```

My biggest trouble is the `f.remove(c)`:

```
z=lambda s,f:f.remove(c) if c in f else 0 for c in s;1
```

The above code just complains with a syntax error.

Note that I am not using this for any serious purpose, just for recreational code golfing.

Comment: You should ask this question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your syntax error has nothing to do with the `remove`; its that you're trying to use list comprehension/generator expression syntax without being in a list comprehension or a generator expression.

Comment: First, why do you want it to be a `lambda` instead of a `def`? Second, it's a really bad idea to use comprehensions, conditional expressions, lambda, etc. for things only being run for side effects.

Comment: @abarnert The lambda is being used for golfing

Comment: If you're code-golfing, then (a) add that in your question, and (b) this is a silly way to do it. Why not just, e.g., use set intersection and then `len` and `==` to get the 0 or 1?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the [`code-golf`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-golf/info) tag has been marked "DO NOT USE" because "Code Golf is no longer on-topic for Stack Overflow given the existence of [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)." However, I don't know whether that means this question should be closed or not, because it's not actually a code-golf challenge, which is what Code Golf is for…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equivalent `lambda`:

```
lambda s, f: int(all(c in f and f.remove(c) is None for c in s))
```

This uses lazy evaluation of `and` and `all` to `remove` only the appropriate characters.

Comment: I think it worth explaining that the lazy evaluation is possible only when using generators and not lists

Comment: @Elisha `all` is still evaluated lazily on a lists, too; the fewest possible elements are tested to be certain of the result. If you made the generator expression a list comprehension by adding square brackets then the code would work differently, sure, but that's true of many different changes to the code!

Answer (score 2):

You *could* write this as a lambda, but you really, really shouldn't.

First, you have to convert each statement to an expression. There are multiple steps here, and every single one of them is a bad idea.

`if c in f: f.remove(c)` becomes `f.remove(c) if c else 0`. It's very unpythonic to use functions called only for their side-effects inside an expression like this, but it's not illegal. We just have to take into account the fact that `f.remove(c)` always returns `None`, and pick something else we can put in the other branch.

Now, that doesn't do an early return, because that's impossible; you can't have a `return` statement, or any statement, inside an expression. We'll get back to that later.

Next, the `for` statement has to become some kind of comprehension, in this case a generator expression: `(f.remove(c) if c in f else 0 for c in s)`. Notice that we're putting the values `None` and `0` into an iterator, even though we don't actually care about those values, so this is a misuse of comprehensions, but again not illegal.

And now we can handle the "early return" by using the `all` function: `all(value is None for value in (f.remove(c) if c in f else 0 for c in s))`. That will be `True` if every value is `None`, but as soon as it finds one that isn't (because `c in f` was false) it will stop, and evaluate to `False`. And we can turn that `False` into `0` and `True` into `1` just by calling `int` on it (or using `1 if foo else 0`, but why bother trying to be Pythonic at this point?) so:

```
z = lambda s, f: int(all(value is None for value in 
                     (f.remove(c) if c in f else 0 for c in s))
```

Of course this is a misuse of `lambda`, since the entire point of `lambda` is that it gives us an anonymous function that can be defined in the middle of an expression; if you want to define it in a statement and give it a name, all you're doing by using `lambda` instead of `def` is obfuscating your code.

You can collapse the two loops into one if you want, and make various other changes to make it more concise if you're going for code golf.

Answer (score 0):

If we're looking for silly ideas, I thought of way to actually return early from an expression. First we need a bit of reusable scaffolding:

```
class Return(Exception): pass

def throw(e): raise e

def early(f):
    try:
        return f()
    except Return as e:
        return e.args[0]
```

Now:

```
z = lambda s, f: early(lambda: [f.remove(c) if c in f else throw(Return(0)) 
                                for c in s])
```

That `early` function won't be necessary if [PEP 463](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/) is accepted, and neither will the inner `lambda`:

```
z = lambda s, f: [f.remove(c) if c in f else throw(Return) 
                  for c in s] except Return: 0
```